# Probability generator

Tags: statistics

> $A$ and $B$ play a game in which they take it in turns to throw a quoit over a peg. At each throw $A$ has a probability of $1/3$ of succeeding, whilst $B$ has a probability of $1/4$ of succeeding. The game continues until one or the other is successful. Find and simplify the probability generators for the total number of throws in a game if
>
> a) $A$ throws first
>
> b) $B$ throws first

Should I draw a tree diagram? Or is this a PGF question?

Comment: *probability generators*... What are they? What kind of glossary does this expression come from?

Comment: Do you mean the expected number of throws, or do you mean a prob. distribution of the number of throws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Probability generator* is not really standard terminology, but it is plausible that the pgf is intended. We solve the "A first" problem.

Let $p_k$ be the probability that the game lasts precisely $k$ throws. We want $\sum_1^\infty p_kt^k$.

It is easy to verify that $p_1=\frac{1}{3}$, $p_2=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$, $p_3=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{3}$, $p_4=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$, and so on forever.

Now let's sum the series. Because the terms have somewhat different shapes for $n$ odd and $n$ even, we handle them **separately**.

Let $f(t)=a_1t+a_3t^3+a_5 t^5+\cdots$, and let $g(t)=a_2t^2+a_4t^4+a_6t^6+\cdots$. Then $f(t)+g(t)$ will be our pgf.

Note that 
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{3}t +\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}t^3 +\cdots.$$
We recognize this as a **geometric series** with first term $\frac{1}{3}t$ and common ratio $\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{4}t^2=\frac{1}{2}t^2$. For suitable $t$, the geometric series has sum
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{3}t \frac{1}{1-t^2/2}.$$
I am sure you can find a similar expression for $g(t)$. Add up, and simplify to taste.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be the number of throws it takes to end the game.  If $A$ throws first, then $P(K=1) = \frac{1}{3}$.  $P(K=2) = \frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{4}$ because $A$ has to fail first.  You can continue this pattern to arbitrary value of $k$.  In general:

$$P(K=k) = \left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}  \left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )^{\lceil k/2 - 1 \rceil} \times \begin{cases} 1/3 & k \: \: \mathrm{odd} \\ 1/4 & k \: \:\mathrm{even} \end{cases}$$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than $x$ and $\lceil x \rceil$ is the least integer greater than $x$.  b) may be analyzed similarly.

**EDIT**

An interesting question for fun is, what is the probability that $A$ wins given that she threw first?  The answer is $\frac{2}{3}$; try to show why.